# Ethernet disconnects after few minutes in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, 16.04, realtek

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 last month and it was working fine till yesterday when my college's server was shifted.Now the connection disconnects after few minutes (although it shows connected),and browser shows "Network was interrupted" error.
Also chrome runs sometimes but firefox doesn't work at all.

I tried this([Ubuntu 16.04 Ethernet issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761036/ubuntu-16-04-ethernet-issues)
) but it did'nt work.

```
On running :    sudo lshw -C network
```

*-network

```
   description: Wireless interface
   product: RT5390 [802.11 b/g/n 1T1R G-band PCI Express Single Chip]
   vendor: Ralink corp.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
   logical name: wlo1
   version: 00
   serial: 7c:e9:d3:9f:92:29
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800pci driverversion=4.4.0-45-generic firmware=0.34 ip=10.42.0.1 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
   resources: irq:16 memory:c3500000-c350ffff
```

*-network

```
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
   logical name: eno1
   version: 05
   serial: a0:b3:cc:70:38:ea
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 100Mbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw ip=172.17.9.63 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
   resources: irq:26 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:c3404000-c3404fff memory:c3400000-c3403fff
```

I a newbie in this kind of matter.Does anyone please have an answer?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I read through the link that you attached in your post and the bit that caught my attention was the ipv6. I've noticed this behavior with IPV6.

How are you connected? Are you in housing, connected to a router, which is connected to a wall? Are you connected over Ethernet or are you connected via WiFi? Are you connected to a unified wireless network as you move about the campus? Does this issue happen on both interfaces or just the one?

The next time that the problem happens, open the shell and type:

`ifconfig`

Look and see what your IP address is.

> Try to ping the gateway
>
> Try to ping 8.8.8.8
>
> Try to ping a different web domain other than what just went offline.

Your send could be failing. You could be connected and your send is succeeding but the route back has an issue so you're not getting a reply. I just went through the no route back issue on a VPN tunnel myself.

If you notice that you have an IPV6 address and that you should be able to connect over IPV4, try the following:

```
sudo dhclient -r <interface-name>
sudo dhclient -4 <interface-name>
```

^^ To clarify above, ^^ The interface name will be found with the *ifconfig* command. Those two commands should force your interface to release the DHCP lease and then request an IPV4 DHCP lease. If you find that this works, you need to edit your interface config so that your network only communicates over IPV4. You can do this through the network manager or manually through config files.